# Oracle : Multiple Pivot columns on the Same numeric column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Data:

```
Vehicle ID        Region      District     City       Revenue
   X50          Southwest      FLD        Miami         50
   X50          Northeast      NYC        Rochester     70
   X70          Southwest      FLD        Miami         20
```

I want to pivot the Region, District and City with the Revenue column.

Output:

```
Vehicle ID        Southwest_R   Northeast_R   FLD_R       NYC_R    Miami_R     Rochester_R
  X50                 50           0            50           0         50         0
  X50                  0           75           0            75         0         75
  X70                  20          0            25           0         25          0
```

The problem I am facing is to add those pivots in a single query.

```
 Select * from table
 Pivot( SUM(Revenue) for Region IN ('Southwest' Southwest_R, 'Northeast' Northeast_R))
```

in this query if I add District and City, it throws error.

Comment: you may want to check this https://community.oracle.com/thread/4074745?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .  This looks like conditional logic not aggregation:

```
select vehicle_id,
       (case when region = 'Southwest' then revenue else 0 end) as southwest_r,
       (case when region = 'Northeast' then revenue else 0 end) as northeast_r,
       (case when district = 'District' then revenue else 0 end) as fld_r,
       (case when district = 'NYC' then revenue else 0 end) as nyc_r,
       . . .
from t;
```

If you can have multiple rows per vehicle, then you can use aggregation:

```
select vehicle_id,
       sum(case when region = 'Southwest' then revenue else 0 end) as southwest_r,
       sum(case when region = 'Northeast' then revenue else 0 end) as northeast_r,
       sum(case when district = 'District' then revenue else 0 end) as fld_r,
       sum(case when district = 'NYC' then revenue else 0 end) as nyc_r,
       . . .
from t
group by vehicle_id;
```